# Javascript compare items in one array

Tags: javascript

Pardon my complete lack of javascript knowledge in advance, but I can't seem to find a good example of how to compare two arrays and create another array based the results.

I am attempting to get a list of user accounts from a storage device (uses javascript and handles MOST functions ok), and compare them against a statically created list of "good" users.

Using a switch statement works but I really do not like it, and I'm sure there is a much better way (userList is populated dynamically from the device when I query it):

```
for (userName = 0; userName < userList.length; userName++) {
    switch (userList[userName]) {
    case 'someuser1':
            printf('Username: ' + userList[userName] + ' is good\n');
            break;
    case 'someuser2':
            printf('Username: ' + userList[userName] + ' is good\n');
            break;
    case 'someuser3':
            printf('Username: ' + userList[userName] + ' is good\n');
            break;
    default:
            printf('Username: ' + userList[userName] + ' is NOT good\n');
    } 
}
```

I would like to create a third array of "bad users" and compare them against a new array of "good users", and "found users". I have started with:

```
var goodUsers = ["someuser1", "someuser2", "someuser3"];
```

However I can't figure out the right combination of multiple for loops, if statements, or otherwise to compare the two and give me an array of the "bad users" that I can loop through and perform actions against.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Array's `indexOf` method is sweet.  It returns the position of an element in the array, if it exists, or returns -1 if it does not.

```
var goodUsers = ["someuser1", "someuser2", "someuser3"];
var users = ["someuser1", 'basuser'];
var user;

for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
  user = users[i];
  if (goodUsers.indexOf(user) >= 0) {
    console.log(user + ' is a good user');
  } else {
    console.log(user + ' is BAD!!!');
  }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qz5fx/1

Comment: Just keep in mind that some older browsers don't have `Array.indexOf()` so you might need a shim if you want it to work in those browsers.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly!  I really appreciate the info on IndexOf also, everything I saw on it didn't explain the -1 value for non-found items, and that is crucial to the test.

Answer (score 2):

Use `indexOf` to find if the user exists in your array.

```
var goodUsers = ["someuser1", "someuser2", "someuser3"];
var storedUsers = ["someuser1", "user", "user3"];
for(var goodUser in goodUsers){
    if(storedUsers.indexOf(goodUsers[goodUser])>-1){
       console.log('User:' + goodUsers[goodUser] + ' is good.')
       }
}
    ​
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that some older browsers (like IE7/IE8) don't have `Array.indexOf()` so you would  need a shim if you want it to work in those browsers.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't return the bad values for me, even when I add an else value.  It returns the good users great, but not bad.  Any ideas?  The method by Alex Wayne works for me, but I am trying to figure out why this did not.

Comment: One should be very careful using `for...in` to iterate over an array.

Answer (score 1):

For larger lists, a more efficient way than `.indexOf` is to put your good user list into an object and use direct lookup on that object.  This also works in older browsers as it doesn't require the `Array.indexOf()` method.

```
var goodUsers = {
    "someuser1": true, 
    "someuser2": true, 
    "someuser3": true
};
```

Then, you can check to see if a user is in that list with:

```
if (goodUsers[user])
```

For longer lists, this is a lot more efficient than using indexOf which just iterates through the array comparing each item in the array to your target because this uses a hash lookup (like a hash table).

If you had a candidate set of users and you wanted to know which ones were in the `goodUsers` list, you could do that like this:

```
var goodUsers = {
    "someuser1": true, 
    "someuser2": true, 
    "someuser3": true
};

var candidateUsers = ["someuser4", "someuser1", "someuser5", "someuser2", "someuser6", "someuser3", "someuser7"];

function checkUsers(candidates) {
    var goods = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = candidates.length; i < len; i++) {
        var item = candidates[i];
        if (goodUsers[item]) {
            goods.push(item);
        }
    }
    return(goods);
}

var validUsers = checkUsers(candidateUsers);
```

---

**Edit:**

While this object lookup still works in modern Javascript, there is now a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object in ES6 that can do this cleaner and more efficiently.  For the user lookup, you would probably use the `Set` object.

```
const goodUsers = new Set(["someUser1", "someUser2", "someUser3"]);
goodUsers.add("someUser4");

if (goodUsers.has(user)) {
    // user is in the set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The brute force method would be something like this:

```
var users = []; // here is where you get the users from the device
var goodUsers = []; // here you get your good users list
var badUsers = []; // initialize an empty array for bad users

for (var i=0; i< users.length; i++) {
    var isAGoodUser = false;
    for(var y=0; y< goodUsers.length; y++) {
        if(users[i] == goodUsers[y]) {
            printf('Username: ' + users[i] + ' is good\n');
            isAGoodUser = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!isAGoodUser){
        printf('Username: ' + users[i] + ' is NOT good\n');
        badUsers.push(users[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `indexOf` method for this. Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8MV3J/

```
var good = ["someuser1", "someuser2", "someuser3"];
var bad = [];
var ugly = ["someuser4", "someuser1", "someuser5", "someuser2", "someuser6", "someuser3", "someuser7"];
var i = 0;
var li;

for (i = 0; i < ugly.length; i += 1) {
    if (good.indexOf(ugly[i]) === -1) {
        bad.push(ugly[i]);
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < bad.length; i += 1) {
    li = $('<li />').text(bad[i]);
    $('ul#bad').append(li);
}​
```