# How to display a pop up when specific product variations (e.g. FREE) added to cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, popup, cart, product

I hope somebody can help me, as I've not been able to find anything relevant yet via Google or Stack Overflow search engine (unless I'm doing something really stupid with my search terms)!

I have a Woocommerce-based site offering a lot of products in various formats and pricing structures.

E.G. A product has these variations: Physical / Digital (Free) / Digital (Paid)

Can anybody point me in the right direction to display a generic pop up (to prompt donations) when free simple products and/ or free product variations are added to the cart?

A further wish would be for this to only occur when there are no paid items already in the cart.

Hope that makes sense - any assistance much appreciated - please request clarification where needed, it's been a long day!

:-) Thank you!

Ed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include details of what you have tried.

Comment: OK, thank you Antimony, I only just signed up here so may have been a little hasty - I'll revisit this in the morning & add further details of my attempts so far!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually how I would be approaching the problem:

Step 1: Install **JavaScript plugin** such as https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/custom-js/

Step 2: Go to Code editor of Wordpress site

Step 3: Open/Edit **Template** option

Step 4: Write a function in PHP to check your "cart" and call a JavaScript function to compare items in your cart

Step 5: Go to the JavaScript plugin, which you have installed earlier, and write this JavaScript function to compare items in your cart and pop up a message (alert dialog) to the user

In case you are wondering how to compare items using JavaScript, given the items are stored in an array, then have a look at this method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092338/4190159

And to pop up alert/message dialog, you can try this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Example of JavaScript to compare and pop up an alert:

```
var allItems = ["PaidItem1", "FreeItem1", "PaidItem2"];
var paidItems = ["PaidItem1", "PaidItem2"];
var item;

for (var i=0; i < paidItems.length; i++) {
  item = paidItems[i];
  if (allItems.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
alert("This is a paid item");
  } else {
alert("This is a free item");
  }
}​
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Somdip, thank you for your speedy feedback! That's interesting - I'm reading through that link now, but unfortunately I'm not too up on JS (past bodging from tutorials)... Would you mind perhaps providing a simple example for me? No worries if that's too big an ask, this is my first post here so I'm still reading through the etiquette info!

Comment: @EdTyler how are you planning to store or add items in your cart?? Do you know or have an idea about the data structure used to save items in the cart?? ....the reason I am asking is because the JavaScript implementation will also depend on the data structure being used to save the items so that they can be compared using a function

Comment: Thanks Somdip - I'm using default Woocommerce to add products to the cart, but it sounds likely that I need to go & do some more basic JS learning before I should get into this! Thanks so much for your advice - all the best!

Comment: Yes, if you need to customise the template to do more than what it offers and to fit your needs then you have to dive inside and do more inside the hood. I have also updated the answer with a basic example of comparing items using JavaScript. And in case you found this answer useful then do not forget to upvote  and mark it as answer. Cheers! All the best and let me know if I can be of any other help.

Comment: Once more, Somdip, you are a true gentleman! I'm going to spend my morning reviewing your additions, so will mark this as an answer once I've taken a deeper look. Thanks again and have a great day!