# Best way to compare elements in an array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare

How do I compare elements in an array using Javascript?

I want to know if `cas[1]`, `cas[2]` and `cas[3]` have the same value.

```
cas = ["0","1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

if(cas[1]== cas[2] && cas[2]==cas[3]){
    console.log("yea");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript compare items in one array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092280/javascript-compare-items-in-one-array)

Comment: im sorry i will edit the question,  i want to know if cas[1], cas[2] and cas[3] have the same value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first of all it's better to use `===`, because `0 == false` is `true`, but `0 === false` is `false`.

`===` works without type casting.

You don't need full cycle loop here, you have to compare only the first 3 elements so `if` statement is ok here.

If you want to do that with every 3 elements, you can do something like this.

```js
const getThreeArrayElements = (array, startIndex) => array.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 3);
getThreeArrayElements([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 0); // [1, 2, 3]
getThreeArrayElements([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 3); // [3, 3, 3]
```

So you can easily get an array with 3 required elements.

The another task is how to compare them.

```js
const areArrayElementsEqual = array => array.every(item => item === array[0]);
areArrayElementsEqual([1, 2, 3]); // false
areArrayElementsEqual([3, 3, 3]); // true
```

Comment: i want to make a tic tac toe, so after i compare if the first 3 elements are same i will compare the second 3 elements, cas [4, 5 and 6]

Comment: @YusufRawat updated

Answer (score -1):

if you're looking for an algorithm to check the entire array :

```js
let cas = ["0","1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

let checkCas  = (cur = 1)=>{return cas[cur-1]===cas[cur]?true:cur<cas.length?checkCas(++cur):false;};

console.log(checkCas());

cas = ["0","1", "2","3","4","5","5","7","8","9"];

console.log(checkCas());
```

as for ticktacktoe :

```js
let casa = ["0","1", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"];

let allEqual  = (cas,cur = 1)=>{return cas[cur-1]===cas[cur]?true:cur<cas.length?allEqual(cas,++cur):false;};

for(let i = 0;i<Math.floor(casa.length/3);i++)
{
   let tempLengArr = [casa[i],casa[i+3],casa[i+6]];
   if(allEqual(casa.slice(i*3,(i*3)+3))||allEqual(tempLengArr)) 
    console.log("won");
   
}

if(allEqual([casa[0],casa[4],casa[9]])||
allEqual([casa[3],casa[4],casa[2]])) console.log("won");
```

might have messed up a bit on my allEqual call but it's an idea

Comment: tnx so much but, it's too complicated for me, I can't read the code hahaha.